# Oracle 12c PARTITION BY RANGE INTERVAL MONTH ORA-01841

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

When working with some partitioning proof of concepts for huge tables (2b+ rows) we came up with some strange behavior of the select statements:

```
create table date_test (
JOURNAL_ID VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
JOURNAL_DATE DATE NOT NULL ENABLE
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (JOURNAL_DATE) INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH')) 
(
PARTITION P_20010101  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('20010101', 'YYYYMMDD'))
);
```

And when running this query:

```
select * from date_test
 WHERE (
 JOURNAL_DATE < TO_DATE('20061201','YYYYMMDD')
 OR 
 JOURNAL_DATE > TO_DATE('20061231','YYYYMMDD')
 ) ;
```

I get the following error:

> ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
>   01841. 00000 -  "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
>   *Cause:    Illegal year entered
>   *Action:   Input year in the specified range

The "interesting" thing is that if you remove one of the clauses on either side of the OR, the query seems to fire up OK. Of course the query works correctly in a non partitioned table.

Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Exactly which version and patch level are you on?

Comment: Try this (undocumented) hint `/*+ NO_EXPAND_TABLE(date_test) */`

Comment: The Oracle version is 12.1.0.2.170117.

Comment: The NO_EXPAND_TABLE hint works, thank a lot Wernfried. Now to investigate what is the impact and how many lines of code we need to revert. Can you set this as an answer so I can mark it as the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like bug, possibly 20961659 or one of its relatives. You may be able to work around it with by changing [the `optimizer_features_enable` setting](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-E193EC9E-B642-4C01-99EC-24E04AEA1A2C.htm#REFRN10141), which you can do as part of your query if you don't want it applied more widely:

```
select /*+ optimizer_features_enable('12.1.0.1') */ * from date_test
 WHERE (
 JOURNAL_DATE < TO_DATE('20061201','YYYYMMDD')
 OR 
 JOURNAL_DATE > TO_DATE('20061231','YYYYMMDD')
 ) ;
```

In 12.1.0.2.170117 I see the same error with your original query; but with that hint it works as expected.

Beware of side effects of course, and if in doubt you can always raise a service request with Oracle Support.

[Read more in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_influence.htm#GUID-325A3D6A-47B8-4AAF-8BB0-4037553D02FE), and also explore the entries related to this error in My Oracle Support.

---

In this case it appears you can also get what you want by reversing the logic to use an inclusive date range with `and`, and negating that with `not`; but you need to stop the optimizer changing it back - this may be overkill again but [a `no_query_transformation` hint](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF50512) seems to do the trick:

```
select /*+ no_query_transformation */ * from date_test
 WHERE NOT (
 JOURNAL_DATE >= TO_DATE('20061201','YYYYMMDD')
 AND 
 JOURNAL_DATE <= TO_DATE('20061231','YYYYMMDD')
 ) ;
```

The [`no_expand` hint](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF50502) doesn't seem to help here; though as @WernfriedDomscheit suggested, the *undocumented* `no_expand_table` hint does seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

try to use  >=

> select * from date_test  WHERE 
>   TO_DATE('20061201','YYYYMMDD')  OR   JOURNAL_DATE >=
>   TO_DATE('20061231','YYYYMMDD')  ) ;(  JOURNAL_DATE <

or use between

> where JOURNAL_DATE between to_date('20061201','YYYYMMDD') and
>   TO_DATE('20061231','YYYYMMDD')

Comment: Your first query is malformed, but if the intention was just change `>` to `>=` then it still errors. The second query doesn't error but the logic is reversed; and if you make it `not between` then it errors again.

Comment: Cannot use <= or >= since it will void the purpose of the query. The code is coming out of a PeopleSoft app engine, I should have added an extra parenthesis on the where clause, as it was on the original query. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: try to change interval to 20061202 and 20061230 
to check if error happens because of interval 
if so you need to revise table partition